# How to compile ffmpeg with librtmp for android in Vitamio 5.0?

Tags: ffmpeg, vitamio

i was using vitamio 4.2.2 but google send me a mail about vitamio libs including security backdoors. And says update vitamio version. But im using vitamio version which was compiled ffmpeg with librtmp android. Now i will use Vitamio 5.0 But How to find ffmpeg rtmp build or who can compile ffmpeg librtmp for Vitamio 5.0 ? Please help me

Comment: did you manage to solve it? im havng similar problem

Answer (score 1):

for you: https://www.vitamio.org/Download/
note: Vitamio 5.0.0 only show dowload for China language.

Comment: I know. I download it. But how can i compile ffmpeg component with librtmp for android. This is not my answer!